# My code doesn't calculate the last values in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

For a school exercise I have to write a program in Python that answers the next question. There was a quiz where a challenger needs to answer a specific amount of questions (n) and a "crack" needs to say if the challenger has picked the right answer. We need to count the amount of correct answers from the challenger and the correct amount of answers from the crack. The input consists of n (= amount of questions), correct (= correct answer: A, B or C), challenger (= answer from the challenger: A, B or C) and crack (= the answer of the crack: correct or wrong).
This is the code I've already made:

```
# Input
n = int(input()) # Number of questions
correct = input() # The correct answer to the question
challenger = input() # The answer from the challenger
crack = input() # The answer from the crack; Is the answer of the challenger correct or wrong?

m = n - 1
a = 0 # Points for the challenger
b = 0 # Points for the crack

for i in range(m):
    if correct == challenger and crack == "correct":
        a += 1
        b += 1
    elif correct == challenger and crack == "wrong":
        a += 1
    elif correct != challenger and crack != "correct":
        b += 1
    else:
        pass
    correct = input()
    challenger = input()
    crack = input()

if a > b:
    print("challenger wins {} points against {}".format(a, b))
elif a == b:
    print("ex aequo: both contestants score {} points".format(a))
else:
    print("crack wins {} points against {}".format(b, a))
```

I have a problem in the for-loop. If there are for example 5 questions (n = 5), the first 4 inputs work, the points of the challenger and crack count like they should. The last series of inputs get into the loop (I've checked it with Python Tutor), but the outcome isn't added to the points of the challenger/crack. How can I fix this bug?

An example of an input is shown here:

```
5
A
A
correct
B
B
wrong
A
C
correct
C
C
correct
C
C
correct
```

Comment: You explicitly remove the last question: `m = n - 1`.

Comment: Thin about putting some text in `input()` method it helps, like `correct = input("Please enter the correct answer")`

Comment: When I used n and there were for example 5 questions, the program wanted a sixth input for some reasons I don't understand, that's why I used the m = n - 1. But with the inputs right after the for-loop (as said in the answer below), I do indeed need to use n (which is more logic ofcourse!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `m = n-1` sets one fewer question than choosen by the user, use directly `n`. Also ask the 3 other element at the beginning of the loop, it avoids the code duplicate, and the last `input` will be used for nothing at the end

```
n = int(input("Number of questions"))
a = 0
b = 0

for i in range(n):
    correct = input("Correct answer: ")
    challenger = input("Challenger answer: ")
    crack = input("Crack answer")

    if correct == challenger and crack == "correct":
        a += 1
        b += 1
    elif correct == challenger and crack == "wrong":
        a += 1
    elif correct != challenger and crack != "correct":
        b += 1

if a > b:
    print("challenger wins {} points against {}".format(a, b))
elif a == b:
    print("ex aequo: both contestants score {} points".format(a))
else:
    print("crack wins {} points against {}".format(b, a))
```